# related content types - "top 10 best movies" functionality

Tags: views, entities

Been trying to achieve functionality like below.
- Article "Top 10 best movies" when you enter the article it is a landing page with short text and then there are links to all ten movies - 10 through 1 like below:

[image]

Tried to do it with two content types - top10(the landing page) and movie(each movie from the top 10 list). Entity reference field on the movie content type pointing to the top10(the landing page). Then made a view listing all movies and filtering by the NID of the main article. But then when I enter the movie content type the links disappear (the nid of the top10 content type is missing). Then tried to make the view to be filtering by the etitiy reference field but then links pointing to other top10 articles appear... Fairly new to drupal and seems like I have meesed it up.

If someone can advise some clean idea would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to build functionality to allow users to see movies under different categories where diff categories are top 10, top 9 ....

Assuming we do not have any criteria to put movies under diff categories instead this is being handled while adding them through a content type.

I am not sure if this will be good solution but might help you,

- Create a vocab as movie rating add terms to it as within top 10,within top 9,within top 8... and so far upto top 1st.
- Add this vocab as term reference to content type responsible for
     generating movie nodes.
- Now every time you add a movie opt the appropriate taoxonomy
     field.
- Create a view for the same content type and keep the movie
     rating vocab as exposed filter as type links for this view, which
     will allow users to select the appropriate category as shared in the
     image in question.so this filter will automatically filter down the
     nodes as per the rating added while creating them.
- Allow your view to use ajax for better user experience.

Comment: wow, actually thats a very nice idea, will give it a try shortly and will let you know. Thank you!